# Send Objects from android client to C server

Tags: android

I want to send objects from an Android client to a C server.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I know how to do it.

Comment: how ? can you please tell me because I search on the internet but I didn't find anything ?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1 :**
Read how to program socket in Android :
 -> http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

**STEP 2 :**
Implements socket in C thanks to ressources which you can find here :

in english :
-> http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

in french :
-> http://broux.developpez.com/articles/c/sockets/
my functions :
-> https://github.com/nekfeu/SocketIO

It's very simple, in 1 hour you will send string from android in your program in C or the contrary

Comment: Thank you, I have already sent string , but I want to send objects ,like information about a person ,etc ,..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Asp.Net Web API for server side